# Function with seperated args as key/value of object without indexer but with computed property name

Tags: typescript, overloading, computed-properties

I am trying to use computed property name in `setState` function where the first arg is a key from the `IState` interface, and second arg is a value of the `IState` interface. And if the first arg is a certain key, then the value must be a certain value. I thought to use overloading like this below, however Typescript is giving me errors. I don't have the errors available right now, but does this look right:

```
enum Qux = {
    qux1 = 'qux1',
    qux2 = 'qux2'
}

enum Foo = {};

enum Bar = {};

interface IState = {
    isLoading: boolean,
    foo?: Foo,
    bar?: Bar,
    qux?: Qux
}

interface IHandleTargetChange {
    (input: 'bar', value: Bar): void;
    (input: 'qux', value: Qux): void;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    handleTargetChange: IHandleTargetChange = (input: any, value: any) => {
        this.setState({
            [input]: value
        });
    }
}
```

It highlights `{ [input]: value }` and gives error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<IState, "isLoading" | "foo" | "bar" | "qux">'.
  Property 'isLoading' is missing in type '{ [x: number]: any; }'. [2345]
(parameter) inputName: any
```

Comment: I think you probably want to turn this into an [mcve] to get good answers; it's quite possible the signature you want looks like `handleTargetChange<K extends keyof IState>(input: K, value: IState[K]): void;` but without code that compiles properly or the particular errors you're seeing it's just speculation.

Comment: @jcalz - updated with error. I didn't have access to the computer so I couldn't post it earlier.